# Dgrid - Firefox breaks while trying to load large data set in dgrid

Tags: javascript, firefox, dojo, dgrid, broken-pipe

**6.30.15 - HOW CAN I MAKE THIS QUESTION BETTER AND MORE HELPFUL TO OTHERS? FEEDBACK WOULD BE HELPFUL. THANKS!**

I have a dgrid connected to a store with a very large data set. (Currently over 137,000 rows). I expect there to be a delay. When I first connected the store - the data populated the dgrid. However I keep getting a pipe break now. I didn't change anything between it working and not working. Currently this is running on a virtual machine. I have three separate clone testing environments, all virtual machines. And I get the same issue with all of them (pipe break).  I created the clones BEFORE they started breaking in each one. I get an (errno 32) broken pipe message or nothing - it just keeps trying to load but not.

I am using FireFox, Dojo 1.10 - OnDemandGrid. Does the same thing in Google.

When the dgrid WAS working I had some issues with it locking up the browser every time I tried to scroll using the scroll bar or if I did a search on the data.

Any recommendations? I can give more information if needed.

ADDED NOTE: I have also tried Grid and Pagination - and doing smaller amounts of data. I consistently get a broken pipe message now.

[image]

Now I'm getting this endless GET request in the browser when trying to load data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know what is wrong per sey, but I would imagine that you are having memory issues.

I was using Gridx with about 15,000 rows and had lots of problems with memory until I implemented the JSONRest store.

For so many rows, I would strongly recommend to use RESTful if you can.

Comment: Thanks! I am using a RESTful. I'm troubleshooting now. I finally got it to work. I minimized the amount of data and got rid of the cache and trackable for now. Will gradually add back in to see what causes it to break.

Comment: I suspect that your server response doesn't match up with the data it's receiving - either it's ignoring the range parameters completely, or it's not responding with enough results to satisfy a range at the "end" of the full result set.  The latter has been known to cause infinite queries in the past.  There really should only be one or two requests at a time in OnDemandGrid, at least initially, and it should only receive 25 or so items.

Comment: Additional Question then... is there a more compatible middleware api REST framework to use other than Django Rest? It seems to have multiple compatibility issues with Dojo, Dgrid, etc. Is there one that might work better? The stack right now is MYSQL database > Python/Django>Django Rest>Dojo>Dgrid. What about Node.js?

Comment: I am using Oracle WebLogic with the Jax-rs library.  I have heard good things about Node.js and Dojo recommends them.